# Android TTS only speaking english

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have a strange issue with Android TTS. I have used `locale.getDefault()` for getting default locale for `tts.setLanguage`. If i change my phone locale to other languages TTS is not speaking anything.

```
@Override
        public void onInit(int status) 
        {
            if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
            {
                try
                {
                    int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());

                    Log.e("LANGUAGE", "Result : " + result  + " " + Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());

                    if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED)
                    {
                        tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   
            }
        }
```

For checking I am using a button click:

```
btn_Check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            String text =et_Check.getText().toString().trim();
            if(!text.equals(""))
                Log.e("Strnig", text);
                tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

        }
    });
```

For `Locale.English` it's working but not for any other language.
Logcat output:

```
 Result : 1 pt
```

Comment: It is likely that the speak call is failing, but the language is supported by network TTS so it's not returning MISSING_DATA or NOT_SUPPORTED.

Comment: why it's failing.I think everything right in the code.isn't it

Comment: If you don't have a network connection, the `speak()` call will fail. You can watch for this using an [UtteranceProgressListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setOnUtteranceProgressListener\(android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener\)). Starting in API 21, you can specifically query for voices that don't require a network connection (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.Engine.html#KEY_FEATURE_NETWORK_SYNTHESIS)).